# Contact Form 7 not sending email using an IP as sender

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I'm using contact form 7 the message is sent but i don't receive any mail.

Here's my Mail Configuration

```
To: name@myemail.com
From: noreply@IPADDRESS // Yes, i'm using IP address in my dev site. ex. noreply@172.11.11.11
Subject: Test
Additional Headers: Reply-To: [your-email]
Message Body: From: [your-name] <[your-email]>
```

I don't know if it's because i'm using IP as sender. Can someone help me on this? Thanks.

Comment: Add all the code for sending the email.

Comment: Easy way to find out: try it with a "normal" from address.  Does it work?

Comment: You need to confirm if it's actually being sent or if Contact Form 7 is just saying it is. The best way to figure this out would be to check your logs. Does your server have access to PHP mail? You may need to use an SMTP plugin. Contact form 7 will actually be sending the email off the server, it doesn't need to be sent from a valid email.

Comment: Hi, I am also interested in this matter trying to use IP address in sender. Did you achieve anything? Have any information?

Answer (score 0):

Try with

> wordpress@172.11.11.11 //Your Sample Ipaddress

To: name@myemail.com
From: wordpress@ServerIPADDRESS
Subject: Test
Additional Headers: Reply-To: [your-email]
Message Body: From: [your-name] <[your-email]>